# How to hide current running process from DDMS Listing

Tags: android, process

I was wondering seeing that Angry bird's and another games's process where not listed in the DDMS process listing.
Do any have idea how to hide our application's process from the DDMS listing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should not appear in the DDMS listing on a production device if the app does not have `android:debuggable="true"` in the manifest. Only debuggable processes will appear in that list.